# setting up the clustered environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I am in process of doing load balancing for DAS 3.0.1. I am planning to use "Minimum High Availability Deployment - DAS 3.0.1". I have gone through your documentation and found below link and description.

Link:-https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Minimum+High+Availability+Deployment+-+DAS+3.0.1

Description:- DAS supports a deployment scenario that has focus on high availability (HA) along with HA processing. To enable HA processing, you should have two DAS servers in a cluster.
For this deployment, both the DAS nodes should be configured to receive all events. To achieve this, clients can either send all the requests to both the nodes or each request to any one of the two nodes (i.e., using load balancing or failover mechanisms). If clients send all the requests to both nodes, the user has to specify that events are duplicated in the cluster (i.e., the same event comes to all the members of the cluster). Alternatively, if a client sends a request to one node, internally it will send that particular request to the other node as well. This way, even if the clients send requests to only one node, both DAS nodes will receive all the requests. 
In this scenario, one DAS node works in active mode and the other works in passive mode. However, both nodes process the whole data.
If the active node fails, the other node becomes active as receives all the requests.

---

I have below questions:-

1. Is it mandatory to send request to both the node.
2. If I send request to node-1 so internally node-1 send request to node-2 then will it create two events in the database. I am afraid if this happen because I do not have the primary key defined for all the stream.
3. If I want to test the clustering how can I test it on the same server.
4. I have not created user and registerd database. It is in the same database. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is clustered No you don't need to.
2. As far as I understand this will not happen if it is correctly clustered and mounted.
3. If you are correctly clustered, you can see `MemberUtils Added member` message in carbon logs.

[image: MemberUtils Added member]

4. As far as I understand for your scenario it should be same DB.